# how to store a very large variable in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed, word-embedding

i have to training a very large embedding dict(about 1TB). I have many machines, so I can use distribute training of tensorflow.

However, I found I cannot construct a very large variable in Parameter Server. Can tensorflow split the variable in different PS automatic?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen anything just yet for **automatic** split (still hunting myself), however, one thought would be to hook into [`Variable Collections`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variables#variable_collections)

> Because disconnected parts of a TensorFlow program might want to create variables, it is sometimes useful to have a single way to access all of them. For this reason TensorFlow provides collections...

specifically looking at [`class VariableV1(Variable)`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#L1156)...

---

... lines `1511` - `1512` ...

```py
    if collections is None:
        collections = [ops.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES]
```

... and lines `1528` - `1530` ...

```py
    self._trainable = trainable
    if trainable and ops.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES not in collections:
      collections = list(collections) + [ops.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES]
```

---

... it *maybe* possible to split your data into a list of variables accessible through `Variable Collections`, but that would still require splitting a rather large variable into smaller chunks which may not be the most memory efficient.

Another thought would use an [`Iterator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Iterator) to read and parse chunks from your source(s) of data instead of loading everything at once.

---

> I'll update if I manage to find a built in before someone else.